# dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image

Tags: kernel, dpkg, dependencies

recently my linux updated the kernel on its own, and because of this my boot out of memory, I am trying to remove the old linux kernel versions: 6.2.0 and 5.19.0.45

```
saba@saba:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
pi  linux-image-5.19.0-45-generic              5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic              5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-50-generic              5.19.0-50.50                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
pi  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic               6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

I am attempting the removal with Mainline Kernels app (I've tried manually too but same thing)

but it displays following error:

```
mainline 1.4.8
uninstall 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1 
Uninstalling 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                                      
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:
 linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-26-generic depends on linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic | linux-image-unsigned-6.2.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-6.2.0-26-generic is not installed.
 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.2.0-26-generic depends on linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic | linux-image-unsigned-6.2.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-6.2.0-26-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic:
 linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic depends on linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
 linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic
mainline: done
```

same error, no matter the kernel version.

when i try to remove it manually i do this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
```

and got this at the end of the logs

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic.postrm ... removing pending trigger
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic': Directory not empty
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
```

```
dpkg --list | head -n 4
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                       Version                                 Architecture Description
```

so how do I remove them? and why is it even happening?

Comment: Which command are you running to remove the kernel? Please include this in your post.

Comment: Please also note the (first three lines of the) header shown by `$ dpkg --list | head -n 4`

Comment: @ArturMeinild updated.